# Preventing hover intent from seeing a mouseleave when moving into an overlaid element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover, hoverintent

This answer:

[cancelling mouseout event when element is overlaid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334654/cancelling-mouseout-event-when-element-is-overlaid)

Gets somewhere near, but isn't really what I am after as it's sort of reversing my problem.

I am making an image gallery similar to the Facebook image viewer.

An image is loaded into an absolutely positioned `div` which is centred on screen and floats above the main page with a z-index value.

To the left and right of the image are small `div` elements with absolute positioning and a `z-index` 1 higher than the image. These `div` elements are left and right arrows to click through the gallery.

The arrows are hidden when the image loads, but then when the user moves his mouse over the image, the arrows should fade in, then if they move off again, they fade out... just as the Facebook viewer does.

I am using `hoverIntent` to achieve this, and it works fine.

BUT... when the user moves his/her mouse into the arrow div, `hoverIntent` sees this as a `mouseleave` event on the image which is underneath and hides the arrow...

So... what I need is to be able to have `hoverIntent` ignore the arrow divs.

The code I am using for `hoverIntent` is quite straight foward:

```
        function showArrows() {
            $('.imgNav').fadeIn(500);
        };
        function hideArrows() {
            $('.imgNav').fadeOut(500);
        };
        $(img).hoverIntent(showArrows, hideArrows);
```

Obviously `img` is the jQuery image object and `.imgNav` is the classname for the arrows.

**EDIT:**

I have created a `fiddle` here: http://jsfiddle.net/jhartnoll/cE6gu/

Comment: could you share rest of the code?

Comment: sorry for delay, been manic. It's quite complex but I'll try to strip out the relevent parts and post above

Comment: I have created a `fiddle` here: http://jsfiddle.net/jhartnoll/cE6gu/

Comment: okay based on example you just need change the way how hoverIntent calls `$('#imageViewer').hoverIntent(showArrows, hideArrows); // set up hoverintent on these menus`, not sure though it it will works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your fiddle example, changing

```
$('.enlarged').hoverIntent(showArrows, hideArrows);
```

to

```
$('.imgViewer').hoverIntent(showArrows, hideArrows);
```

did the trick for me http://jsfiddle.net/cE6gu/4/

Note, on hoverintent website it says its designed to ignore children ([here](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)) so you just need to make sure you call hoverintent on a parent element that contains all these divs.

Comment: Lovely! Didn't realise it was that simple!